# Graph free disk space on windows systems

Tags: windows, software-rec, disk-space

What is a good and simple tool to monitor and graph free disk space over time on
a windows machine?

The usual disk visualization tools are not a good fit, as the result should be an timeline of the free disk space.

Comment: Peter - Deleting the link to the duplicate just makes it more difficult for others. Please don't do that. If you disagree with the duplicate or it doesn;t solve your problem then mention in comments and in chat. Perhaps with a bit of modification your question will be re-opened.

Comment: I once cobbled one together to check disk spaces on a load of remote sites servers. It was very low tech but it did the job just fine for what i wanted.

Comment: I used powershell, very nice and powerfull for such adhoc monitoring tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run a script that checks the free space on the HDD you want to look at. The output could be set to append to a text file. You could then use Excel to graph it. Very low tech but fairly easy to set up and free.